# Lvalue decaying to rvalue with auto error

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, lvalue

I apologize if the question title is inaccurate - but I am having difficulties understanding what is going on here.

Consider the following class:

```
struct foo {
    foo(foo&);
};
```

The following has no errors:

```
void func(foo& f) {
    foo bar{f};
}
```

However, when I use auto:

```
void func(foo& f) {
    auto bar = foo{f};
}
```

I get (gcc):

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void func(foo&)’:
test.cpp:6:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::foo(foo)’
test.cpp:6:21: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:2:5: note: foo::foo(foo&)
test.cpp:2:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘foo’ to ‘foo&’
```

(clang)

```
test.cpp:6:10: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'bar'
    auto bar = foo{f};
         ^     ~~~~~~
test.cpp:2:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
    foo(foo&);
    ^
```

Can somebody please explain why this is an error?

Thanks!

Edit:  It works if I add a copy-constructor to foo.  However, I was under the impression that the variable declaration + explicit call to constructor on the right side of the '=' syntax is treated specially and is not a copy-construction but rather a direct initialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
auto bar = foo{f};
```

`auto` is deduced as `foo`. Subsequently, your definition is equivalent to

```
foo bar = foo{f};
```

You are trying to create an object of type `foo` that is copy-initialized with the prvalue  `foo{f}`.

The problem is that the copy constructor of `foo` has a non-const lvalue reference as its parameter, which is impossible to bind to an rvalue. Also, the move constructor isn't implicitly defined as you have a user-declared copy constructor. Hence there is no constructor that can take `foo{f}`, and the compiler issues an error message.

Comment: Will the compiler emit a call to the copy constructor?  I was under the impression that the compiler would treat this as a direct initialization.

Comment: Ahh typing on android is slow, and there seems to be no way to delete the answer as well

Comment: @RobertMason The compiler may elide a call to a copy constructor which has no side-effects, but the copy constructor must still be callable.

Comment: @RobertMason Regardless of whether the call would be *elided*, the constructor must be invoke-able and produce a valid call.

Answer (score 3):

```
auto bar = foo{f};
```

This is copy-initialization, and by its semantics it requires the presence of copy constructor. However, the copy constructor of `foo` takes non-const reference, and non-const reference cannot be bound to temporary, that is  `foo{f}`.

The solution is to make a copy constructor which takes const reference, as copy constructors usually do.